# ssh соединение без paramiko

Tags: linux, python-2.7

Как можно управлять ssh соединением в python, если `paramiko` не доступен?

Задача следующая: есть сервер A на нем мой софт, нужно получить данные с ноды который находится за кластером B.

Запускаю через `subprocess` ssh  соединение с кластером B, выходит так: `subprocess.Popen(['ssh', host, 'cli'])`, где `cli` - это команда которая собирает данные о доступных нодах.

После того как я нашел нужные мне ноды, я добавляю их имена в список и должен запустить соединение ssh кластер B -> нода, и выполнить команду на ноде, чтобы собрать нужные мне данные с кластеров.

Какими способами можно решить данную задачу без `paramiko` и не изобретая новый велосипед. Спасибо за советы!

Comment: "нода" - Node.js  или узел кластера?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Раз в тагах `linux` добавлю однострочник на `bash/shell`

```
~$ ssh user@host_A "ssh user@host_B ls"
```

Выполнит команду `ls` на  host_B после подключения сначала к **host_A** потом к **host_B**, наличие авторизации по ключу должно быть настроено заранее.

Вкратце, вам необходимо знать под каким пользователем заходить сначала на **host_A** потом на **host_B**

**Ссылки**

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586106/perform-commands-over-ssh-with-python